# XML request body: invalid on Windows Azure

Tags: xml, azure, virtual-machine, provisioning

```
  <PersistentVMRole xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <RoleName>SomeName</RoleName>
      <RoleType>PersistentVMRole</RoleType>
      <ConfigurationSets>
        <!--Include either a WindowsProvisioningConfigurationSet or a LinuxProvisioningConfigurationSet, but not both -->
        <ConfigurationSet>
          <ConfigurationType>WindowsProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationType>
          <ComputerName>cedvill00</ComputerName>
          <AdminPassword>MyPassword!</AdminPassword>
          <EnableAutomaticUpdates>true</EnableAutomaticUpdates>
          <TimeZone></TimeZone>
          <DomainJoin>
            <Credentials>
              <Username>user-name-in-the-domain</Username>
              <Password>password-for-the-user-name</Password>
            </Credentials>
            <JoinDomain></JoinDomain>
            <MachineObjectOU></MachineObjectOU>
          </DomainJoin>
          <StoredCertificateSettings>
            <CertificateSetting>
              <StoreLocation>LocalMachine</StoreLocation>
              <StoreName>teststorageaccounts</StoreName>
              <Thumbprint>DD3914C952CAC255C1CB15D5A0A35C3C3D008FCC</Thumbprint>
            </CertificateSetting>
          </StoredCertificateSettings>
          <WinRm>
            <Listeners>
              <Listener>
                <Type>Http</Type>
              </Listener>
              <Listener>
                <Type>Https</Type>
              </Listener>
            </Listeners>
          </WinRm>
          <AdminUsername>Cedvill00112233!</AdminUsername>
        </ConfigurationSet>
        <!--<ConfigurationSet>
          <ConfigurationType>LinuxProvisioningConfiguration</ConfigurationType>
          <HostName>host-name-for-the-vm</HostName>
          <UserName>new-user-name</UserName> 
          <UserPassword>password-for-the-new-user</UserPassword> 
          <DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>true|false</DisableSshPasswordAuthentication>           
          <SSH>
            <PublicKeys>
              <PublicKey>
                <FingerPrint>certificate-fingerprint</FingerPrint>
                <Path>SSH-public-key-storage-location</Path>     
              </PublicKey>
            </PublicKeys>
            <KeyPairs>
              <KeyPair>
                <FingerPrint>certificate-fingerprint</FingerPrint>
                <Path>SSH-public-key-storage-location</Path>
              </KeyPair>
            </KeyPairs>
          </SSH>
        </ConfigurationSet>-->
        <ConfigurationSet>
          <ConfigurationSetType>NetworkConfiguration</ConfigurationSetType>          
          <InputEndpoints>
            <InputEndpoint>
              <LoadBalancedEndpointSetName>Remote Desktop</LoadBalancedEndpointSetName>
              <LocalPort>3389</LocalPort>
              <Name>RemoteDesktop</Name>
              <Port>80</Port>
              <LoadBalancerProbe>
                <Path></Path>
                <Port></Port>
                <Protocol></Protocol>
                <IntervalInSeconds></IntervalInSeconds>
                <TimeoutInSeconds></TimeoutInSeconds>
              </LoadBalancerProbe>
              <Protocol>TCP</Protocol>                    
            </InputEndpoint>
          </InputEndpoints>
          <SubnetNames>
            <SubnetName>FrontEndSubnet1</SubnetName>
            <SubnetName>BackEndSubnet1</SubnetName>
          </SubnetNames>
        </ConfigurationSet>
      </ConfigurationSets>
      <AvailabilitySetName></AvailabilitySetName>
      <DataVirtualHardDisks>
        <DataVirtualHardDisk>
          <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
          <DiskLabel>myDiskLabel</DiskLabel>
          <DiskName>newname</DiskName>
          <Lun>3</Lun>
          <LogicalDiskSizeInGB>16gb</LogicalDiskSizeInGB>
          <MediaLink>http://teststorageaccounts.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/TestsRock.vhd</MediaLink>
        </DataVirtualHardDisk>
      </DataVirtualHardDisks>
      <OSVirtualHardDisk>
        <HostCaching>ReadWrite</HostCaching>
        <DiskLabel>myosdisklabel</DiskLabel>
        <DiskName>newname</DiskName>
        <MediaLink>http://teststorageaccounts.blob.core.windows.net/vhds/TestsRockets.vhd</MediaLink>
        <SourceImageName>03f55de797f546a1b29d1b8d66be687a__Visual-Studio-2013-Preview-Ultimate-12.0.20617.1</SourceImageName>
      </OSVirtualHardDisk>
      <RoleSize>Small</RoleSize>
    </PersistentVMRole>
```

I have this request body to create VM. What I want to accomplish is to create many VMs on one cloudservice but unfortunately my request body is invalid, and I cant find whats wrong. Can anyone help me out here or provide some working sample. I followed this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157186.aspx). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just want to assure that you know that the Windows Azure VMRole has retired and now you can use more the Windows Azure IaaS Virtual machine, here are the following links that can help you more:

What is Windows Azure Virtual Machine:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/services/virtual-machines/

Migrate Windows Azure VMRole to Windows Azure Virtual Machine:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn133483.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I believe the documentation is not up-to-date. Please try adding the following node

```
<AdminUsername>adminusername</AdminUsername>
```

after

```
<AdminPassword>MyPassword!</AdminPassword>
```

node.

Also, if you get a WebException, you could try to read the response of that WebException and that should give you more details about the error. For example:

```
    catch (WebException webEx)
    {
        using (var respStream = new System.IO.StreamReader(webEx.Response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var detailedErrorMessage = respStream.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
```

Here, `detailedErrorMessage` should give you an XML with more details about the error.

Comment: still same error.
detailedErrorMessage returns to me empty(white space).
Im requesting to this: https://management.core.windows.net/subscriptionID/services/hostedservices/CloudService/deployments/Production/roles

is this right?

Comment: What's the exact error you're getting? You're performing `Add Role` operation. Based on the documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj157186.aspx, the request URL should include `deploymentname` however I think you're passing `deployment slot` there. Can you please try by providing a valid deployment name? Currently you're trying to do a lot of things in your request. May I suggest that you start by creating just the VM and leave everything else out. It may help you pinpoint the error faster.